# iOS Push Notifications via JavaPNS - no badge number shown

Tags: java, ios, push-notification

So, after much gnashing of teeth, I finally managed to get Push notifications to work in Apple's development sandbox environment.  All is well - I am using the very basic code with Push.alert which works well - here is a sample:

```
            try {
                Push.alert(message, "dev_cert.p12", "xxxxxxxx", false,
                            r.getToken());
                rdr.setLastNotified(new java.util.Date());
            } catch (CommunicationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (KeystoreException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Although I can see the messages appear in the pull down, and the little roll-over notification on the top of the screen, there is NO badge number on the app itself!  What gives??  Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you set the badge number in the push message?

Comment: Ummm no I didn't, I thought push from Apple would do that??  If no, I can definitely do it myself..

Comment: Actually rckoenes, that doesn't make sense, because, the code I am showing above is Java code running on my server, and my app is not running, so I cannot turn on the badge number, only the push notification can do that...

Comment: Yes you are correct, but you must set the application badge number in the push notification.

Comment: rckoenes, do you know if the badge number (or the increment value) can be set in the Java api (JavaAPNS)?  I guess, that is at the root of the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the "fix" - the fix involves actually reading the documentation of JavaAPNS - simply use this API:

```
try {

    // message (String), badge # (int), sound (String), certificate (String), password (String), production (boolean true/false - false is for sandbox), token (String)

Push.combined(message, 1, null, cert, "verysecretpassword", false, r.getToken());


        } catch (CommunicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeystoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
```

Now sadly, the iphone has no way of keeping a track of the NUMBER of the badge (it does not auto-increment), you the developer must keep a track of that on the server.